# declaring integer in for loop of a function giving error

Tags: c++, c

I cannot find out what's wrong in this code:

```
    using namespace std;

    const int sz = 10000+100;
    int sqr[sz];
    int digit;

    void findSqr()
    {

        for(int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++);
        {
            cout<<sqr[i]<<endl;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        findSqr();
        return 0;
    }
```

When I'm initializing int I in for loop in findsqr function and trying to build the code then an error appears

name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]|
How should I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from the end of the `for` statement, that is, replace

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++);
```

with

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
```

Nevertheless, bear in mind that loops without a body (i.e. not followed by curly braces) are also possible C language constructs. These **are** followed by a semicolon.

Comment: ah... that semicolon ... enemy of programmers. thanks btw

Comment: For future reference, problems caused by a simple typographical error should be closed, not answered.